# How do I classify a float as an integer?

Tags: python, printing, integer

```py
a = int(input("Geef de a waarde van de vergelijking: "))
b = int(input("Geef de b waarde van de vergelijking: "))
if a == 0 and b != 0:
    print("Er is geen gehele oplossing.")
elif a == 0 and b == 0:
    print("Er zijn meerdere gehele oplossingen.")
elif a != 0 and b == 0:
    print("De gehele oplossing is x = 0.")
elif (b/a) != 0 and type(b/a) == int:
    print("De gehele oplossing is x = " + str(b/a) + ".")
elif (b/a) != 0 and type(b/a) != int:
    print("Er is geen gehele oplossing.")
```

I need to make y = ax + b and i need to tell which are the points where the function is zero. My problem lies with the last two elif's. When i put a = 6 and b = -54 it calculates it as the last elif: (b/a) != 0 and type(b/a) !=int. While when you calculate -54/6 you become -9. It's as if the programe doesn't count negative numbers as integers. I'm working with dodona and I've noticed in the correction that the only that are false are the ones that classify as elif (b/Ba) != 0 and type(b/a) == int. I know that when you devide its automatically a float type. But i don't know any other option to seperate the two.
P.S. the print from the last elif says "there are no integer results". the print form the elif before that says "the integer result is x = (b/a) ."

I have tried to do it with the float type but i don't know how to classify it as an integer when it's an float.

Comment: The result of a division will always be a float. For example, 54/9 = 6.0 ; if you want to check whether the result is an integer, you can perform the test `y/x == int(y/x)`

Comment: If you want to know if the the remainder is zero (so the result would be an int) you can do `a % b == 0`. Also instead of doing `type(x) == y` it is generally recommended to do isinstance(x, y)

Comment: To answer the title of the question, you can classify a float as an integer by calling the [`float.is_integer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer) method, e.g. `(b / a).is_integer()`.

Comment: `(b/a) != 0` if and only if `b != 0`

Answer (score 0):

Use `%` and check for remainder. For floats remainder will be non-zero. You need to update like below. (No need for `(b/a) != 0` as they are already checked for `0` in previous `if/elif`).

```
elif b % a == 0:
    print("De gehele oplossing is x = " + str(b/a) + ".")
elif b % a != 0:
    print("Er is geen gehele oplossing.")
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, python division operator `/` will always return a value of type float; for example `54/6 = 9.0`.
To make the second to last `elif` do what you want, you can check if the remainder of the division is `0`, since if that is the case, then the division yields an integer result.
The python [modulo operator](https://realpython.com/python-modulo-operator/), `%`, does exactly this and thus you can use :

```py
elif (b/a) != 0 and b % a == 0:
```

instead of

```py
elif (b/a) != 0 and type(b/a) == int:
```